# time complexity exercise (pseudo code)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Just started Data Structure. Got stuck on this one:

[image]

I am having trouble with the inner while and for loops, Because it changes if the N number is odd or even.

My best case will be - the inner for loop runs logn (base 2) times,
And the while loop - logn times (base 2)

Would love some help.

Comment: You are trying to give a big-O, not an exact count of the number of operations. Even vs. odd shouldn't matter. In any event, if you want help with your homework, you should include your attempted solution.

Comment: Well i added my best guess. I Just need some guidance..

Comment: Did you cover how to evaluate the sum `1+2+2^2+2^3+...+2^(k-1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concentrate on how many times `do_something()` is called.

The outer `for` loop clearly runs `n` times, and the `while` loop inside it is independent of the variable `i`. Thus `do_something()` is called `n` times the total number of times it is called in the `while` loop.

In the first pass through the `while` loop, `do_something()` is called once. The second time, it is called twice, the third time it is called, 4 times, etc.

The total number of times it is called is thus

```
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^(k-1)
```

where `k` is maximal such that `2^(k-1) <= n`.

There is a standard formula for the above sum. Use it then solve for `k` in terms of `n` and multiply the result by the `n` from the outer loop, and you are done.